# How do you use reactive-native-drawer with a navbar? (React Native iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

I've created a navbar with a 'Menu' button as its left button. Once clicked, I'm trying to get the following drawer menu ( https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer ) to slide out from the side, the left side, and use the drawer menu for navigation among different views.

The following is what I have set up for the navbar's left 'Menu' button:

```
var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState){
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={()=>{
            if(index > 0){
              navigator.pop()
            }
          }
        }
      >
        <Text style={styles.leftNavButtonText}>Menu</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  },
```

I am stuck as to what should go inside the ()=> for onPress to reveal the react-native-drawer by getting it to slide out from the side?

And as for the react-native-drawer alone, if I am going for drawer menu like Slack's with a few buttons, should it be in ListView or ScrollView?

NEW EDIT:

```
var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState){
          return(
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={()=>{this._openDrawer.bind(this)}
          }
        }
      >
        <Image source={require('./src/img/menuIcon.png')} style={styles.leftNavButtonImg}/>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  },
```

Comment: Are you using something to manage application state like Redux, MobX, etc? Can you show your drawer setup?

Comment: @rmevans9 Currently I am just storing via this.state. Would that be flux? What's the recommended state management application for React Native? I've updated the code under NEW EDIT but the only difference is that I now have a function _openDrawer once clicked, but from there what should I call or implement to get the drawer to slide out?

Comment: You will need to have some sort of application state management setup. I can't speak to the recommendation as I do not know because I generally pick based on personal preference after playing with all the options. I personally use Redux.

Comment: @rmevans9 I'll check them out. In the meantime, do you mind guiding me with the NEW EDIT?

Comment: I am not sure what you want me to guide you with? There isn't much that can be done to open/close the drawer from a component other then the one containing the drawer until you have your application state managed more globally. The reason being is you will call an action on the global state management to set the drawer to open (or closed) and then have the drawer listen to that.

Comment: @rmevans9 If you can show how to implement to get the drawer to open up -- slide out -- once the LeftButton is clicked, would greatly appreciate it. Still stuck on it.

Comment: Without knowing what your application state management setup of choice is not really. The best I can give you is an explanation conceptually of how it would work.